# What’s this orange stuff growing on my snake plant?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, houseplants, indoors, fungus

[image]

I just noticed these things growing alongside my snake plant. Should I take them out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Bird’s Nest Fungus, and is treated by leaving it alone as it does no harm to the plant.